# Constrained optimization for $u(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\alpha \min \{a x_1, b x_2\} + \beta \min \{c x_3, d x_4 \}$

Tags: microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, optimization

Suppose preferences are represented by the following utility function

\begin{equation}
u(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\alpha \min \{a x_1, b x_2\} + \beta \min \{c x_3, d x_4 \}
\end{equation}

Write the

1. Walrasian demand functions
2. Hicksian demand functions
3. Indirect utility function
4. Expenditure function

---

**Remark**

I come from a math background and my only experience with economics are (so far) the first three chapters of the book *Microeconomic Theory* by Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green. Following their approach, I want to solve the following 
utility maximization problem

\begin{equation}
\max_{\vec{\mathbf{x}}\in \mathbb{R}^4} \{u(\vec{\mathbf{x}})\} = \max_{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4} \{\alpha \min \{a x_1, b x_2\} + \beta \min \{c x_3, d x_4 \} \}
\end{equation}

s.t. $p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 = w$

to get the Walrasian demand functions $x_i(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w)=x_i(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,w)$. Then I could get the indirect utility function by substituting these solutions into the utility function:
\begin{equation*}
v(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w)=u(x_1^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w),x_2^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w),x_3^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w),x_4^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},w))
\end{equation*}
Similarly, to get the Hicksian demand functions $h_i(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,u)$, I would solve the expenditure minimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\min_{\vec{\mathbf{x}}} \{\vec{\mathbf{p}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{x}}\}
=\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4} \{p_1x_1+p_2x_2+p_3x_3+p_4x_4\}
\end{equation*}
and then get the expenditure function by multiplying
\begin{align*}
e(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u)
&=\vec{\mathbf{p}} \cdot \vec{\mathbf{h}}^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u)
 \\
&=p_1 h_1^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u) +p_2 h_2^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u)+p_3 h_3^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u) + p_4 h_4^*(\vec{\mathbf{p}},u)
\end{align*} 
Although I can visualize the entire process, I'm stuck at the beginning - solving the constrained utility maximization and expenditure minimization problems. Starting with the utility maximization problem, I want to write the Lagrangian
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda)=\alpha \min\{a x_1, b x_2 \} + \beta \min \{c x_3, d x_4\}+\lambda(w-p_1x_1-p_2x_2)
\end{equation*}
and take the first order conditions
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)}{\partial x_i}=\lambda p_i
\end{equation*}
however I don't know how, mathematically, to take the above first order conditions with respect to $x_i$ since $\min$ isn't everywhere differentiable. (However, as [this answer points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150960/derivative-of-the-fx-y-minx-y), the partial derivatives of our objective function exist *almost* everywhere.)

This is my first experience with solving for demand functions, aside from the Cobb-Douglas example provided in the book Microeconomic Theory. Could anyone help me complete this example?

Comment: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/finding-demand-function-given-a-utility-minx-y-function?rq=1 should help you. In particular  the first sentence "No, you should not use Lagrange multipliers here, but sound thinking."

Comment: Great. Now you need to solve for different cases. Assume that $ax_1 > bx_2$ and find the solutions. Then assume other way around and solve again. Similarly for $x_3$ and $x_4$. You will have different solution for different prices.